# FXML: how to keep buttons in center when resizing window?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to design a UI in FXML and by partly using Scene Builder. I use an Anchorpane to place all the content in the scene. However, when I resize the window to a greater size, the buttons move from the center to the left. I want to make sure they stay in the center of the page. How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Post your `FXML` file. If it's very big, post a watered down version that only shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you are simply placing all of your content inside an `AnchorPane`, you will potentially have plenty of problems due to things like resizing, font change, and resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to make use of [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) or [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html). In case of BorderPane, you can keep the button or container containing the button at center position using Pos.CENTER.

If AnchorPane is really needed, you can make use of width and height property change listeners to adjust button position during resizing.

```
private AnchorPane anchorPane;
private Button button;

anchorPane.widthProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        button.setLayoutX(newValue.doubleValue()/2 - (button.widthProperty().getValue() / 2));
    });
anchorPane.heightProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        button.setLayoutY(newValue.doubleValue()/2 - (button.heightProperty().getValue() / 2));
    });
```